# Remove Row Padding In QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

After filling a QTableWidget table I call:

```
table->resizeRowsToContents();
```

This makes the rows narrower but there is still a lot of padding between each row, as you can see here:

[image: Table After resizeRowsToContents()]

Looking at the documentation I found I could set the hight of each row with:

```
table->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(16);
```

This removes the padding and gives me the tight spacing I want:

[image: Table After setDefaultSectionSize(16)]

However, I'm concerned about using an absolute size in pixels.  If the the system font is set to something large the text might not fit in the row.

Is there a way to remove the padding between rows while ensuring the text will always fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom delegate with the `QAbstractItemDelegate::sizeHint()` method implemented in a way that it will return a correct size according to the font used.

To compute a correct height, you can use a `QFontMetrics` provided with the *option* parameter of the `sizeHint()` method.

```
int height = option.fontMetrics.height();
```

or more precisely

```
int height = option.fontMetrics.boundingRect(index.data().toString()).height();
```

**EDIT: How to use a delegate:**

```
CMyDelegate* delegate = new CMyDelegate(tableView);
tableView->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good solution.  I'm new to Qt a bit confused where QAbstractItemDelegate comes in.  Would it not be easier to subclass QTableWidgetItem and override the sizeHint() method in the way that you describe?

Comment: I have updated my answer a little. And yes, you can also subclass the `QTableWidgetItem` and reimplement the `sizeHint()` method there.