# Remove unwanted padding/spacing in QTableWidget cells

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, spacing, qtablewidgetitem

I've created a QTableWidget and populated its last column with `QPushButton`s added inside a `QButtonGroup` (given in the code below):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class ModTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(0, 3)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Alias", "Path", ""])
        
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) 
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

        self.is_default_group = QButtonGroup()

        for item in range(10):
            self.addItem(str(item), str(item))

    def addItem(self, alias, path):
        last_row_index = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(last_row_index)

        alias_item = QTableWidgetItem()
        alias_item.setText(alias)
        self.setItem(last_row_index, 0, alias_item)

        path_item = QTableWidgetItem()
        path_item.setText(path)
        self.setItem(last_row_index, 1, path_item)

        is_default_btn = QPushButton("Btn")
        is_default_btn.setMaximumWidth(30)
        is_default_btn.setCheckable(True)

        self.is_default_group.addButton(is_default_btn)
        self.setCellWidget(last_row_index, 2, is_default_btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    tablewidget = ModTableWidget()
    tablewidget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It is working fine, but it adds a little space on the last column:

[image]

I assume that it adds that little space by default, as it's also noticeable on the images in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922952/remove-row-padding-in-qtablewidget). The most relevant question I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680533/remove-cell-padding-from-qtablewidget-in-pyqt5), in which they talked about implementing custom painting through a delegate - though I'm not sure if this is the right path as I'm somewhat new to this concept.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on arch-linux (using qt-5.15.5 and pyqt-5.15.7). There's no gap at all, and changing the widget-style to fusion or windows makes no difference. I assume the gap is somehow produced by the vertical scroll-bar being present before the window is resized and shown on screen. If you add the line `self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)`, does the gap disappear?

Comment: I tried adding the line in but the gap is still there as can be seen in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/lmT8mfg.gif). Maybe it's not because of the vertical scroll-bar since [this](https://i.imgur.com/TKmWTNc.gif) is what it looks like with the vertical scroll-bar.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to eliminate that possibility. See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this may be caused by the [minimum section size](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#minimumSectionSize-prop) of the horizontal header. This value partly depends on the current style and font, so it may differ between systems. On mine, it happens to be 30px, which coincidently matches the maximum width set on the buttons - so I don't see a gap. Presumably on your system it must be slightly wider. Anyway, adjusting the value should hopefully fix the issue for you:

```
    print(self.horizontalHeader().minimumSectionSize())
    self.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(30)
```